# Qt TLS initialization failed

Tags: qt

ide is Clion, Qt6.2.2, MSVS 2019, 64 bit, windows 10 21H1

i want to replace Clion with Visual studio (the program can work in vs)

the code is

```
QNetworkAccessManager manager;
manager.get(request);
```

qDebug() << QSslSocket::supportsSsl() << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString() << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString() << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionNumber();

show: false, "", "", -1

my cmake:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt\\6.2.2\\msvc2019_64")
set(INC_DIR C:\\Qt\\Tools\\OpenSSL\\Win_x64\\include)
set(LINK_DIR C:\\Qt\\Tools\\OpenSSL\\Win_x64\\lib)
include_directories(${INC_DIR})
link_directories(${LINK_DIR})
link_libraries(libcrypto libssl)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS
        Core
        Gui
        Widgets
        Network
        REQUIRED)

add_executable(untitled
        main.cpp 
        )


target_link_libraries(untitled PRIVATE
        Qt6::Core
        Qt6::Gui
        Qt6::Widgets
        Qt6::Network
        OpenSSL::SSL
        OpenSSL::Crypto
        )
```

program run show:

```
qt.network.ssl: No TLS backend is available
qt.network.ssl: No functional TLS backend was found
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed
false "" "" -1
```

cmake show:

```
C:\Users\mainj\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\213.6461.46\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles" C:\Users\mainj\CLionProjects\untitled
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29914.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29914.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenSSL: C:/Qt/Tools/OpenSSL/Win_x64/lib/libcrypto.lib (found version "1.1.1j")  
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Performing Test HAVE_STDATOMIC
-- Performing Test HAVE_STDATOMIC - Success
-- Found WrapAtomic: TRUE  
-- Could NOT find WrapVulkanHeaders (missing: Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Found WrapOpenSSLHeaders: C:/Qt/Tools/OpenSSL/Win_x64/include (found version "1.1.1j") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/mainj/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was solved by self.
it's just use `windeployqt.exe` to import all library.

every is all right.

Answer (score 0):

what solved it for me was:
I copied next to my executable the tls folder containing 3 files

```
qcertonlybackend.dll
qopensslbackend.dll
qschannelbackend.dll
```

The Location of these files were not there in qt 5.5
This solved it for me with qt 6.5.1
I hope this helps someone else as well